Source array was not long enough. Check the source index, length, and the array's lower bounds. (Parameter 'sourceArray')
I'm encountering an issue with my code developed using .NET 8 and C#. The error message I'm receiving is:
Source array was not long enough. Check the source index, length, and the array's lower bounds. (Parameter 'sourceArray')
StackTrace:
{
    "title": "Internal Server Error",
    "detail": "Source array was not long enough. Check the source index, length, and the array's lower bounds. (Parameter 'sourceArray')",
    "traceId": "6e643d65-cd90-4de1-859f-0891813950fe",
    "status": 500,
    "stacktrace": "   at System.Array.CopyImpl(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)\r\n   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Array destinationArray, Int32 length)\r\n   at Shared.Core.Utilities.FileValidator.ValidateFileBinaryType(IFormFile file, MemoryStream ms) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\Utilities\\FileValidator.cs:line

The error occurs in the following method , part of FileValidator.cs :
public static bool ValidateFileBinaryType(IFormFile file, MemoryStream ms)
{
    // Copy the file content to the MemoryStream
    file.CopyTo(ms);

    // Get the length of the file
    long fileLength = ms.Length;

    // Rent an array from the ArrayPool
    byte[] fileBytes = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent((int)fileLength);

    try
    {
        // Copy the MemoryStream to the rented array
        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)fileLength);

        // Read the first 16 bytes of the file
        byte[] fileData = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(fileBytes, fileData, 16);

        // Convert the byte array to a hexadecimal string
        string hexData = BitConverter.ToString(fileData);

        // Extract the first 23 characters from the hexadecimal string
        string inputFileHexaCode = hexData.Substring(0, 23);

        // Extract the first 11 characters from the hexadecimal string
        string inputPDFFileHexaCode = hexData.Substring(0, 11);

        // Check if the file is an Office file ending with 'x' (e.g., .docx, .xlsx, .pptx)
        if (inputFileHexaCode.Equals(BinaryFileTypeConstants.officeEndsWithXType, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        {
            return ValidateOfficeFile(fileBytes, fileLength);
        }

        // Check if the file is a PDF or an Office file not ending with 'x'
        if (CheckValidFileType(inputFileHexaCode, inputPDFFileHexaCode))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Return the rented array to the ArrayPool
        ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(fileBytes);
    }
}


What could be causing the "Source array was not long enough" error
in this context?
How can I ensure that the array operations are safe
and do not result in this error?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Can anyone help me here with some code sample which will serve as a reference for my implementation?

Please show the full stack trace, not just the message . At the moment we can't tell for sure which method is causing the problem. It would also help if you could tell us what the file length is. (What do you expect to happen if the file is less than 16 bytes long?)

it looks like fileBytes is too short. Check the debugger and tell us the size of it

Thanks @JonSkeet for you response. I have updated the question with stacktrace details.

The exception occurs when the length of fileBytes is less than the 16 bytes you told Array.Copy to copy.  This could happen if file.CopyTo(ms); writes fewer than 16 bytes to the memory stream ms.  The implementation is not provided in your question to debug further.

Thanks @Wyck for your response. If I put a condition : if (fileLength < 16){ return false;} will it resolve the issue is what I wanted to know.

Why are you reading the entire file before you test whether it is a valid type? It would be simpler to just read the first 16 bytes and process them first. You can also check whether the file is actually long enough to contain at least 16 bytes.

@santoshkumarpatro Yes, adding if (fileLength < 16) return false; after assigning a value to fileLength will avoid that one exception.  But you have an additional problem that MemoryStream.Read is not obligated to fill out all 16 bytes.  The docs say An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached.  So even though the array will be of a sufficient size to avoid the exception, you really must check the return value of ms.Read as well to see how many bytes were written to know if they are valid.
